# Graylog Cluster node Journal metrics unavailable | Failed to call API on node

Tags: graylog

I have installed a clustered Graylog Server. When I navigate to system/nodes , I encounter the error “Journal metrics unavailable,” specifically on the host that is connected via VPN(IPSec)

graylog log:

```
2024-01-19T14:12:53.099+05:00 WARN  [ProxiedResource] Failed to call API on node <58faa302-ac63-48b7-b17e-a383b269aeeb>, cause: timeout (duration: 1002 ms)
2024-01-19T14:13:53.177+05:00 WARN  [ProxiedResource] Failed to call API on node <58faa302-ac63-48b7-b17e-a383b269aeeb>, cause: timeout (duration: 1003 ms)
2024-01-19T14:14:02.013+05:00 WARN  [ProxiedResource] Failed to call API on node <58faa302-ac63-48b7-b17e-a383b269aeeb>, cause: timeout (duration: 1003 ms)
2024-01-19T14:14:03.938+05:00 WARN  [ProxiedResource] Failed to call API on node <58faa302-ac63-48b7-b17e-a383b269aeeb>, cause: timeout (duration: 1002 ms)
2024-01-19T14:14:05.942+05:00 WARN  [ProxiedResource] Failed to call API on node <58faa302-ac63-48b7-b17e-a383b269aeeb>, cause: timeout (duration: 1003 ms)
```

192.168.60.81(graylog01kar) and 192.168.62.115(graylog03kar) are on different VLANs, but they are in the same location. They can see each other, but they cannot see 192.168.25.81(graylog01ten) specifically.
192.168.25.81 is in another location connected via site-to-site VPN (IPSec) and there are no issues; all metrics are visible.